# Can I avoid Microsoft.XMLDOM parsing error with different dtd or schema?

Tags: html, xml, dom, xsd, dtd

I am getting various parse errors using loadXML.  Is there some way I can set a less strict dtd or something like that?

Code being loaded:

```
<h3 id="group_text" class="groupbox_header_text" style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;">Time & Day</h3>
```

Failed for reason:

reason "Whitespace is not allowed at this location."

I think this is because of the & symbol.

Thanks,

Grae

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can only use an XML parser to parse XML. Your input is not well-formed XML. Your only options are to (a) change the input to be well formed XML; or (b) not use an XML parser. i.e. use an HTML parser instead.